# Java regex replaceAll to replace exact value

Tags: java, regex

As mentioned in the title, here is the sample input

I will having this kind of input

```
String str = "test_String test_String#ID\ntest_String#ID test_String";
```

then i using this code to replace the code above

```
regex = "test_String";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(Example1);
str = m.replaceAll("abc");
```

the output i get will become
"abc#ID abc"

the output i wanted is "test_String#ID abc"

Comment: Do you want to simply skip the first instance of your regex's match, or is there some other criteria you are looking to skip on?

Comment: not just skip the first instance, because the occurrence of the pattern might come first or come later. so i need the filter to be exact match then only perform replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
regex = "(?m)(?<=\\s|^)test_String(?=\\s|$)";
```

Which means match `test_String` only if it is surrounded by a whitespace or line start/end.

**Code:**

```
String str = "test_String test_String#ID\ntest_String#ID test_String";
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?m)(?<=\\s|^)test_String(?=\\s|$)", "abc");
```

**Output:**

```
abc test_String#ID
test_String#ID abc
```

Comment: Hi anubhava i updated the sample input, in the updated scenario ur code are not working....

Comment: `"test_String test_String#ID\ntest_String#ID test_String"` has 2 lines of input. What is your expected output for each line?

Comment: abc test_String#ID
test_String#ID abc

Comment: extra question here, if i want to replace this "test_String#ID" the regex did not find any matches....

Comment: You need to clarify the logic when `test_String` should be replaced and when it should not be replaced in a line

Comment: just tested actually ur code is working well... just when i apply to my actual scenario it still not working.... which i also very curious why....

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Hello {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String str = "testString#ID testString\ntestString testString#ID";
        String repl = str.replaceAll("(testString)(?!#)", "abc");
        System.out.println(repl);
    }
}
```

Comment: please share in java not javascript

Answer (score 0):

package com.test;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class StackOverflow {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //String Example1 = "testString#ID testString";
    //String Example2 = "testString testString#ID";
    String Example3 = "test_String test_String#ID\ntest_String#ID test_String";
    String regex = "test_String";
    String replaceWIth = "abc";
    String delimiter = " ";
    StringTokenizer tokens  = new StringTokenizer(Example3, delimiter, true);
    // if you want fix the buffer size by 
    // ((Example1.length()/regex.length()) * replaceWIth.length()) + (Example1.length()%regex.length())
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String t = tokens.nextToken(); 
        if (t.equals(regex)) {
            buffer.append(replaceWIth);
        } else {
            buffer.append(t);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: almost there please try the following input, the logic should able to handle these scenario as well

String str = "test_String#ID test_String\ntest_String test_String#ID";